# How can I add another naming context to my ldap server using the olc method?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to add another naming context to my ldap server using the olc, but so far I am new to this and haven't found a example explaining this. I guess I could use a tool like apacheDS but I want to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It's another database. You will have to look at an existing database entry and figure out how to clone it and what to change. I would dump the OLC database config to an LDIF file, modify it, and load it as a new subtree, rather than trying to do it all strictly online.